# attempting to return to async task when error is thrown and handled

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, async-await, try-catch

i have written my own custom exceptions to handle possible errors in my code. for example i have ConnectionException, OperationsException and DownloadException which are thrown when i cant do any of the operations to help me pinpoint the error.

i have a method takes a list:

'''result = await Task.Run(function() DoSomething(FileName, directory))'''

the called method DoSomething throws the exceptions back to this method where its caught. My question is that i want to catch the exception thrown at me then continue with the loop, currently i catch the error and then the loop breaks and i have message displaying the error.

is there a way to implement this within vb.net? - so i get the exception then continue with the rest of the list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean like [`Try`/`Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement)?

Comment: nope, i have a try catch implemented. which works fine and i get the exception handled, but im trying to catch the exception then returning to the task to continue, without exiting out of the working method

Comment: You cannot resume a task that has already completed with an error. You'd have to *restart* it.

Comment: hmmm looks like ill have to structure this a bit differently then. thanks